# How can I store 15 years of older MacOS Mail on an external drive?

Tags: macos, email, archive

I started with Eudora files and converted them to Mac Mail files. Now I have the Eudora files, which I can easily locate onto an external disk because they're flat files.

But I also have that decade+ of converted mail taking up a huge amount of room on my Mac.

I don't want to delete the Mac Mail files, but I want to move them off of my computer and onto an external disk. They are in mailboxes since the Eudora files were sorted into mailboxes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of existing questions/answers that address this very topic:

- [Archiving mail from Mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71403/archiving-mail-from-mail-app)
- [Archiving Apple Mail to an External Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131074/archiving-apple-mail-to-an-external-drive)
- [Move mail boxes data to external drive on Mac Mail on Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/move-mail-boxes-data-to-external-drive-on-mac-mail-on-mavericks)
- [Moving individual Mailbox to external drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104953/moving-individual-mailbox-to-external-drive)

These posts should get you on the right track to migrating your mail over to the external disk.

Basically, what you need to do is either copy/move the mbox file to the external drive or use the Export function in the Mail app to export mail to a mailbox located on the external drive.